# Warning: Array.prototype.reduce() expects a return value from arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const singleParams = [...appliedFilters].reduce((prev, curr) => {
    if (curr.key !== "multi")
        return { ...prev, ...curr.selectedValue.params };
    return;
}, {});
```

The following function is giving me the following warning in my console.

> Line 22:13:  Array.prototype.reduce() expects a return value from
> arrow function  array-callback-return

I can't ignore it since I won't be able to deploy with warnings. How do I fix it?

Comment: It is due to the `return;` statement, try returning a value instead of `undefined` (say `return prev;`)

Comment: when you use the flower braces {} you need to have a return. In case you don't want that then use the parenthesis ()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return `prev` in else block

```
  const singleParams = [...appliedFilters].reduce((prev, curr) => {
        if (curr.key !== "multi")
            return { ...prev, ...curr.selectedValue.params };
        return prev;
    }, {});
```